# Función rollback() no revierte el autoincremento en una tabla de MySQL

Tags: mysql

Estoy usando Node.js en el backend de mi aplicación y MySQL para la base de datos, he hecho varios insert en una tabla con PK auto incrementable y también una FK, he estado haciendo pruebas usando transacciones pero cuando la FK falla, además de no insertarse el registro hago un rollback para que la PK no aumente pero siempre lo hace. Quiero saber a qué se debe este comportamiento.

Está es mi función:

```
async function testInsert() {
   const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');

   const options = {
       host: process.env.DB_HOST,
       port: process.env.DB_PORT,
       database: process.env.DB_NAME,
       user: process.env.DB_USER,
       password: process.env.DB_PWD,
   };

   const connection = await mysql.createConnection(options);

   try {
       await connection.beginTransaction();

       const result = await connection.execute('INSERT INTO users (fullname, age, job_id)', ['Example', 27, 25]);
       await connection.commit();

       return result;
   } catch (error) {
       await connection.rollback();
       return error;
   }
}
```

Comment: es un comportamiento totalmente normal. si haces un intento de insert y falla, el ID se considera como "usado" y pasa al siguiente

Comment: Es es el comportamiento natural de los autonumericos creo que en todos los motores es así. Un autonumerico solo asegura que un número no se repita no que no haya huecos. ¿A que se debe este comportamiento? a una decisión de diseño, y por lo que te comentaba antes, el único requerimiento que se le exige a un autonumérico es que no se repita.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya entiendo lo que sucede. Prácticamente los campos auto incrementables son se pueden revertir con rollback.